# Base Class Pointer Assigned to Derived Class and Polymorphism

Tags: c++, pointers, polymorphism

For the following code, when the base class pointer is assigned to derived class, I have questions about polymorphism.

When the objects of derived class directly use the print functions, the outputs are obvious.

When I use base class pointers and point to objects of derived class, the print function of the base class will be used, but the outputs are information from derived objects. Can anyone explain in detail why? Thank you!

```
class Person {
public:
    Person() {};
    Person(string nm):name(nm) {};
    void print() const;
private:
   string name;
};

class Student : public Person {
public:
    Student(int num, string nm) : IDNumber(num), Person(nm) {};
    void print() const;
private:
    int IDNumber;
}

class Employee : public Person {
public:
    Employee(int num, int sal, string nm) : IDNumber(num), salary(sal), Person(nm) {};
    void print() const;
private:
    int IDNumber, salary;
}

void Person::print() const {
    cout << name << endl;
}

void Student::print() const {
    cout << "GoGoGo! ";
    Person::print();
}

void Employee::print() const {
    cout << "I work: ";
    Person::print();
}

int main() {
    Person per("Peter");
    Student stu(3141, "Sally");
    Employee emp(2718, 40, "Edward");

    Person* ptr = &per;
    Person* ptr2 = &stu;
    Person* ptr3 = &emp;

    per.print();   //Peter
    stu.print();   //GoGoGo! Sally
    emp.print();   //I work: Edward

    ptr->print();  //Peter
    ptr2->print(); //Sally
    ptr3->print(); //Edward
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Which outputs are you not understanding?   `ptr3->print();` calls `Person::print()` on `emp`, but `emp.print()` calls `Employee::print()`.  The output of `ptr3->print()` only contains information which is stored in `Person` so I am not sure what you meant by "the outputs are information from derived objects".

Comment: For example, stu: stu.print() will output "GoGoGo! Sally", but ptr2->print will only output "Sally" even though it points to stu.

Comment: `ptr2` has type `Person *`, so `ptr2->print` calls `Person::print()`.   `stu` has type `Student`, so `stu.print` calls `Student::print()`

Comment: note: this is not polymorphism  (polymorphism would be when you want to call functions in the derived class using a base class pointer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function `print()` is not `virtual`, therefore is not polymorphic. The function on the base class is hiding the function of the child class.

The only thing you have to do to make the code work as expected is to make `print()` virtual in class `Person`:

```
class Person {
public:
    Person() {};
    virtual ~Person() {};
    Person(string nm):name(nm) {};
    virtual void print() const;
private:
   string name;
};
```

Note that I added a virtual destructor, this is required to every class that is intended to be inherited.

The output shows the information of the derived objects because child classes inherit the members of the base class (i,e. `name`, which is set to Peter, Sally and Edward).

Comment: I learned polymorphism from Java. So I don't know enough details about the real polymorphism implementation in C++. Thank you for the explanation.

Comment: note: the virtual destructor is only required if you intend to use `delete` on a base-class pointer to delete the derived object.  However there is no harm in pre-emptively using it as you have done, since there's no overhead given that you already had a virtual function.

Answer (score 0):

The key word for the behavior of code is "Static Binding and Dynamic Binding".

When compiler reads the following statement at compile time, it sees, ptr3 is of Person type, it check person class and replaces print() with function address of print that is defined in Person class. All this happens compile time and that's why called static binding.

```
ptr3->print();
```

Why is it able to print information that was entered through derive class object ?

In the following statement, you are calling constructor of Base class and entering information in base class member. ptr3* is of Base class type so it has access to its members.

```
Employee(int num, int sal, string nm) : IDNumber(num), salary(sal), Person(nm) {};
```

If, you make int salary; a public member in Employee class and try to access through

ptr3-> salary

It will give error

> ptr3 has no member of named salary

As salary is member of derive class and base class object has no access over it.